# Unexpected token \n in JSON when parsing with Elm.Json

Tags: elm

Actually I'm working with Elm but I have few issues with the json parsing in this language, the error that give me the compiler is:

```
Err "Given an invalid JSON: Unexpected token \n in JSON at position 388"
```

What I need to do is this:

[example](https://image.prntscr.com/image/e51c0c0774c4463abc3482209bd442d4.png)

At the char_meta I want its something like this:

```
[("Biographical Information", [("Japanese Name", "緑谷出久"), ...]), ...]
```

Here the code:

[Ellie link](https://ellie-app.com/3dbvLCxrP7Ma1/2)

PD: The only constant keys are character_name, lang, summary and char_meta, they keys inside of char_meta are dynamic (thats why I use keyvaluepair) and the length its always different of this array (sometimes its empty)

Thanks, hope can help me.

EDIT:

The Ellie link now redirect to the fixed code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that elm (or JS once transcoded) interprets the `\n` and `\"` sequences when parsing the string literal, and they are replaced with an actual new line and double quotes respectively, which results in invalid JSON.

If you want to have the JSON inline in the code, you need to escape the 5 `\`s by doubling them (`\\n` and `\\"`).

This only applies for literals, you won't have the issue if you load JSON from the network for instance.

Comment: So many thanks!!!! I was trying all day to fix this error!

I have updated the ellie link with the correct code, just a fix is not `\\"` its `\"` 

Again so many thanks!